# Finding all combinations of doubles (having two elements) out of a list

Tags: php, c, algorithm, combinations

Say my list is 
`{1,2,3,4}`

My title may not be descriptive enough but here is what i want to do..
I want my code to generate the following

`{ (1,2) , (3,4) }`

`{ (1,3) , (2,4) }`

`{ (1,4) , (2,3) }`

`{ (2,1) , (4,3) }`

`{ (3,1) , (4,2) }`

`{ (4,1) , (3,2) }`

i.e i want all the 4C2 combinations of the set.

Note: here the initial four elements is just an illustrative number.. the number may vary uptill 8 or 10.

Now, how do i write the code for it (in C or php).

Basically, i want to know the algorithm. not the whole of it., even a headstart will be good enough.. 
I just cant think of anything to start from.
Kindly help. 
Thanks.

I guess i did not explain it well; actually i did not get the problem myself.
what i want is that, say i have 4 teams and i want to play every team against the other then how do i generate all the fixtures.
in my example above; considering 1,2,3,4 as 4 teams.  and 
{(1,2), (3,4)} as a set of fixtures and so on.
how do i do this.
hence what i need is to generate all the NC2/ (N/2) set of fixtures. (N=4 in this case)

Comment: Will it always be `nC2` or it could be `nCr`?

Comment: You could modify the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435552/php-array-combination

Comment: Follow @mathematical.coffee's advice....Use permutation and simply group 2 consecutive items together. Presto! :)

Comment: Why do you want `{ (1,4) , (2,3) }` and `{ (4,1) , (3,2) }` but not `{ (4,1) , (2,3) }`?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard because 4,1  and 2,3 has 2,3 that is already covered in 1,4 and 2,3.

Comment: I guess I am not familiar with this type of combination.  Where does, and does not, order matter?  It seems like `(1,2)` could be paired with either `(3,4)` or `(4,3)` -- how is this chosen?

Comment: haha.. ok.. it is ust like..
say there are 4 teams and i want them to pair up, say like fixtures, such that every week every team has a match.. considering once all combinations have been done, then there reciprocals are also there..
i.e. in the qustion... the first 3 sets take care of all the fixtures, and the last three take care of the reciprocals..
it is true that 1,2  could have been paired with 3,4   or 4,3..
but then 2,1 would be paired with the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically, i want to know the algorithm. not the whole of it., even a
>   headstart will be good enough.. I just cant think of anything to start
>   from.

If you want a headstart, the Python docs show the algorithm used for its implementation of a combinations function.  Replace the range() with a plain for-loop and the *yield* with a *printf* and it should be easy to translate into C or PHP: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Note the combinations of four things taken two at a time yields:  `(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)`.  Your sample output also includes the complement of each (i.e. `(1, 2)` is accompanied by `(3, 4)`).

Answer (score 1):

I made this (PHP). I added a third parameter which can be used to have the function return every possible combinations whether or not the order of the elements matters. The initial option set and the return combinations will be arrays

```
function every_combinations($set, $n, $order_matters = false) {
    $combinations = [];
    foreach($set AS $k => $e) {
        $subset = $set;
        unset($subset[$k]);
        if($n == 1) $combinations[] = [$e];
        else {
            $subcomb = every_combinations($subset, $n - 1, $order_matters);
            foreach($subcomb AS $s) {
                $comb = array_merge([$e], $s);
                if($order_matters) $combinations[] = $comb;
                else {
                    $needle = $comb;
                    sort($needle);
                    if(!in_array($needle, $combinations)) $combinations[] = $comb;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $combinations;
}
```